# Create concatenated observable loop with dynamic length

Tags: javascript, loops, rxjs, refactoring

I have a function that gives me the next word based on a string array input, and appends the array:

```
getNextWordAndAppend(stringArray: string[]) {
    // parse
    return this.title.getNextWord(word).pipe(
      map((result: {}[]) => {
        const nextWord = // next word from objectArray
        stringArray.push(nextWord ? nextWord.toString() : "")
        return stringArray.filter(item => // some filtering logic)
      })
    )
  }
```

Say I want to chain this function, and pass on the value of the previous observable to the next, to create a sentence:

```
initialize() {
    this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
        // parse input
        concatMap((stringArray: string[]) => this.getNextWordAndAppend(stringArray)),
        concatMap((stringArray: string[]) => this.getNextWordAndAppend(stringArray)),
        concatMap((stringArray: string[]) => this.getNextWordAndAppend(stringArray)),
        // parse output
    ).subscribe()
  }
```

Say I want to dynamically determine the iterations of this final observable, how do I create a function like below? It takes an Observable as input and should also return one.

pseudocode:

```
    //
    .pipe(
        // Initial value, Observable to loop, and number of iterations 
        concatAndPassResult(["Hello", "world"], this.getNextWordAndAppend, 50)
    )
```

What would `concatAndPassResult` look like? Something with `reduce`?

Comment: so the initial value only append in the. first time looping?

Comment: No, the first function will take a string array, add a word, and pass the new array to the next function, that function will append a word to the string array, pass it to the next function, etc

Comment: but looks your initialValue from the code is coming from the form value?

Comment: Correct, first user input is a string array, which I pass on to an observable, which gives me a new string array, which I need to pass on to the same observable, which gives me a new string array, which I need to pass on to the same observable, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expand` to recursively run async observable and append results. `take` can complete the stream for a specified number of execution.

Because the initial value is coming from an observable source, so i changed your function signature a bit.

`getWords` here is to simulate a async call which return random word

```
import { from, of, timer } from "rxjs";
import { map, takeWhile, take, tap, expand } from "rxjs/operators";

const getWords = timer(1000).pipe(map(() => "someword" + Math.random()));
const concatAndPassResult = (stream, count) => (source) => {
  return source.pipe(
    expand((value) => stream.pipe(map((v) => [...value, v]))),
    take(count)
  );
};

of(["Hello", "world"])
  .pipe(concatAndPassResult(getWords, 40))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```